# Global application menus implemented for LibreOffice in stable release?

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

The Natty betas never implemented Global Menus for LibreOffice. Have Global Menus been implemented in the stable release of Natty?

Answer (score 1):

It's available but not by default, you need to install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install lo-menubar
```